# SQLite (php) fetchArray() not stopping at end of results

Tags: php, sqlite, phpunit

I'm trying to test some of my models.  I use dependency injection to select the database methods. I already have working models, but I'm trying to go back and have tests so that I can start working TDD instead of hope-and-pray...

Before I can start testing my model, though, I have to get my database abstraction proven. I wrote an abstraction for SQLite3 to mimic the abstraction I use for ODBC. My plan is to use SQLite for testing my models.

> What I am having trouble figuring out is why the `while` loop in
>   `testDbSqLiteFetchObjectImplementation2()` never stops. 
>   `$this->abstraction->fetchObject()` should return `false` when it's
>   done iterating over the results. But it tries to keep going which throws an Undefined Property Error.

Any ideas why it doesn't return false are appreciated :)

**db_sqlite.class.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * SQLite Database Abstraction
 *
 * This class is a database abstraction that allows consistent and simplified methods for
 * accessing databases, along with db_db2.class.php and db_odbc.class.php
 **/ 
class DB_sqlite {

  public function __construct($database = "", $user = "", $password = "") {
    $this->db = new SQLite3(':memory:');
  }

  public function prepare($query) {
    $this->statement = $this->db->prepare($query);
  }

  public function bind($vals='') {
    settype($vals, 'array');

    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($vals); $i++) {
        $this->statement->bindValue(($i+1), $vals[$i]); // bindValue index starts at 1, not 0
    }
    $this->result = $this->statement->execute();
    return $this->result;
  }

/**
 * OOP method for retrieving a row of db.  Use in a while statement that assigns results to a var, ie
 *
 *     while($row = $db->fetchObject()) { 
 *       print $row->COLUMN_NAME; 
 *     }
 *
 * @return object Typically the returned object's properties must be accessed as ALL CAPS
 */
  public function fetchObject() {
    return (object)($this->result->fetchArray());
  }

/**
 * Associative Array method of retrieving row
 */
  public function fetchRow() {
    return $this->result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

  }
```

**sampleTest.php**

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require("../scripts/task_config.php");

class sampleTest extends TestCase {

    public function setupDb() {
        $this->abstraction = new db_sqlite;
        $fields = 'HISTID NUMERIC,ORGID NUMERIC,STATUS TEXT';

        // note $this->abstraction calls db_sqlite's 'db' property 
        // which is a `new SQLite3(':memory:')` object
        $this->abstraction->db->exec("CREATE TABLE tableName ($fields)");
        $this->abstraction->db->exec("INSERT INTO tableName (HISTID,ORGID,STATUS) VALUES (1, 101, 'c')");
        $this->abstraction->db->exec("INSERT INTO tableName (HISTID,ORGID,STATUS) VALUES (2, 102, 'c')");
    }

    public function testDbSqLiteFetchRowImplementation() {

        $this->setupDb();

        $this->abstraction->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE STATUS='c'");
        $this->abstraction->bind();

        $row = $this->abstraction->fetchRow();
        $this->assertEquals('101', $row['ORGID']);

        $row = $this->abstraction->fetchRow();
        $this->assertEquals('102', $row['ORGID']);

    }

    public function testDbSqLiteFetchObjectImplementation() {

        $this->setupDb();

        $this->abstraction->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE STATUS='c'");
        $this->abstraction->bind(); // db abstraction binds and executes.

        $row = $this->abstraction->fetchObject();
        $this->assertEquals('101', $row->ORGID);

        $row = $this->abstraction->fetchObject();
        $this->assertEquals('102', $row->ORGID);

    }

    public function testDbSqLiteFetchObjectImplementation2() {

        $this->setupDb();

        $this->abstraction->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE STATUS='c'");
        $this->abstraction->bind();

        $count = 0;
        print "\n";
        while($row = $this->abstraction->fetchObject()) {
            print ++$count;
            $collection[] = $row->ORGID;
        }

        $this->assertEquals('101', $collection[0]);
        $this->assertEquals('102', $collection[1]);

    }
}
```

**test results**

```
$ cmd //c phpunit
        PHPUnit 6.0.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..E                                                                3 / 3 (100%)
Number of while loop iterations:
123

Time: 339 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) sampleTest::testDbSqLiteFetchObjectImplementation2
Undefined property: stdClass::$ORGID

X:\tests\sample2Test.php:66

ERRORS!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 4, Errors: 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your abstraction class you're explicitly casting the value returned by the database into an object. So even if it's `false`, after casting it to object, the value will not be "falsy". This makes the loop running infinitely.

The code you need to fix is in `fetchObject` method:

```
return (object)($this->result->fetchArray());
```

Change it to something like

```
$res = $this->result->fetchArray();
if (!$res)
    return $res;
return (object)$res;
```

Comment: *facepalm* I'll give that a try tomorrow

Comment: Good job you decided to add a test!

Comment: Sometimes the obvious problems are the hardest to find... Thanks for the eyes.  I swear I had tried that already.  re: testing, the more I play with it, the more i like it!